# Can I retrieve source code from a compiled WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, decompiling

I have been working on a project for my college course for a couple of months. When I went to submit it the other day the source code has gone missing. It was a WPF C# application. Because all of the work was done on my memory stick I have no backup of it.

I tried running a recovery tool but it was unable to find anything.

What I have is the following:

- The contents of the `bin > Debug` folder including an up to date compiled version of the application (an `exe` file)
- The `.sln` file for the project.

I really need the source code for this as without it I might end up failing the project. Is there any way to get it with what I have?

Comment: You can get a decompiled version of it using something like [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).  It might not be the prettiest code, and you'll need to recreate the solution and the XAML yourself.

Comment: Another tool that lets you see the source code is [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/). It even has a feature to create the complete project along with all files for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have DLLs you can use something like .netReflector and peep into code..

use dlls in a new project and then you can drill into them